# Python pickle silently fails to dump empty python dictionary

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have a python program that needs to be able to erase the data saved in pickle file. However, it simply doesn't write the file. The code that fails is here:

```
with open("passwords.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump({}, f)
    print("success")
```

I tried to run the same code shown above in the python REPL and it works flawlessly, yet it fails with no exception thrown when run in the script. To be sure I wrote the code correctly, I pasted my code from the REPL directly into my script and it still fails to write. The file has no changes.